# How to convert custom string date format to desired output SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, date-conversion

In SQL server, I have a date string that looks something like 09/08/2021. Representing dd/MM/YYYY. So in this case its 09 August 2021. Every method I attempt converting this explicitly into a date format automatically converts this to 2021-09-08. So SQL incorrectly converts to 08 September 2021.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(Convert(VARCHAR(15),'09/08/2021',103) as date);
SELECT TRY_CAST(Convert(VARCHAR(15),'09/08/2021',111) as date);
```

Both incorrectly give:

```
2021-09-08
```

Desired result is:

```
2021-08-09
```

I've tried the various different versions of the above but keep getting the incorrect conversion. I don't really want to go down the road of changing the source data either.

I am amazed no similar question has been previously asked regarding this.

How can this be converted explicitly using functions in SQL Server?

Comment: `CONVERT` accepts a style when converting to a `DATE`, but you're converting to a `VARCHAR(15)`. You want `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '09/08/2021', 103)` instead.

Comment: Why would you expect a format at all? `date` is a binary value, it has *no format*. The format is for your presentation layer to determine *not* the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, it was the conversion that was the mistake. Adjusted to

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '09/08/2021', 103)
```

This fixes the issue.